# How can i use push notifications to send the data tied to the the user that created the push event?

Tags: swift, push-notification

I've been struggling with this issue for the better part of five days now and am unable to come up with a solution. Im hoping you all will be able to help me out. :) I am currently in my 10th week of a coding bootcamp so please excuse any mistakes I make in my terminology. Thank you.

So... Here is my problem. A user creates an event and that event send a notification to all the user of the app. ( V.2. will use location to only send it to those near you )  Once you receive that push notification i want the app to open a specific view and populate the fields with the information from the User that created the event. let me show you my code.

```
 // Youre CRUD Methods go here.

func createEvent(eventSummary: String, eventLongtitude: Float, eventLatitude: Float, eventCreationDate: NSDate, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

    guard let currentUser = UserController.sharedInstance.currentUser else { return }

    let event = Event(creator: currentUser, eventCreationDate: eventCreationDate, eventLatitude: eventLatitude, eventLongtitude: eventLongtitude, eventSummary: eventSummary)

    saveContext()

    if let completion = completion {
        completion()
    }

    if let eventRecord = event.cloudKitRecord {
        cloudKitManager.saveRecord(eventRecord, completion: { (record, error) in
            if let record = record {
                event.update(record)
            }
        })
    }
}

func retrieveEventForRecordID(recordID: CKRecordID, completion: (Event) -> Void) {

    self.cloudKitManager.fetchRecordWithID(recordID) { (record, error) in
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("Error fetching event for record ID \(recordID): \(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let record = record else { return }

        if let event = Event(record: record) {
            completion(event)
        }
    }
}
```

This shows my createEvent method that should take in the user that created the event.

```
func userWithName(userRecordID: CKRecordID, completion: ((user: User?) -> Void)?) {

    cloudKitManager.fetchRecordWithID(userRecordID) { (record, error) in
        if let  record = record {
            if   let user = User(record: record) {

                if let  completion = completion {
                    completion(user: user)
                }
            }

        } else {
            if let completion = completion {
                completion(user: nil)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is whats in my App delegate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    guard let remoteNotificationDictionary = userInfo as? [String: NSObject] else { return }
    let cloudKitNotification = CKQueryNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: remoteNotificationDictionary)
    guard let recordID = cloudKitNotification.recordID else { return }

    let eventController = EventController.sharedInstance
    eventController.retrieveEventForRecordID(recordID) { (event) in
        // do whatever with this event

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            // show table view

            let eventAlert = UILocalNotification()

            eventAlert.alertTitle = "Place holder for title"
            eventAlert.alertBody = "Place for body" // This is the local. This is what the user will see.

            application.presentLocalNotificationNow(eventAlert)

            print("Alert has been sent... maybe... prolly not." )

            // TODO: alert to show users that there was an event.


            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            guard let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventNotifVC") as? EventNotificationTableViewController else { return }
            destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
            destinationViewController.event = event

            if let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController {
                rootVC.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that with those code snippets it should show my line of thinking. Create and event with a user. -> make it the creator -> and with that creator populate fields... Im so lost with this... Any help would be appreciated.

Also, this is how I'm setting the label..

```
 func updateViews() {
    guard let event = event,
    creator = event.creator else {
        // Update views to be blank?
        return
    }

    userEventSummaryTextView.text = event.eventSummary
    usernameLabel.text = creator.username
    userPhoneNumber.text = creator.phoneNumber

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateViews()
}
```